# How to see workflow variables values when debugging WF 4 Workflow Activity

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

I am new to Workflow Foundation and I am unable to see what value the `Activity` variable is being set to.  I have set a break point in the activity but the locals window does not show anything.

How do I check the `Activity` variable's values when debugging?

Answer (score 0):

What is the thing you are you calling "Activity variable"?
Are you referring to the In/Out Arguments of an Activity?

Comment: yes,But now i am able to get values during debugging

Answer (score 0):

You can view the value of an "In" argument by viewing the activity in its XAML (code) definition and hovering over the argument's attribute value when the debugger is paused. You can also dig around inside the private properties of the DataContext member of the activity's execution Context to see all the information about the Variables. Sadly, it is far from intuitive, but sometimes gives you enough information to figure out what's happening for yourself.